# How to fix boot error for install on a RAID 5 configuration

Tags: installation, raid, boot-repair

I'm trying to install ubuntu onto a 6TB virtual disk (3 3TB drives in a RAID 5 configuration).

I thought I had it all ready to go.  But it doesn't boot.

So, then I tried boot-repair, which claimed to fix problem.  But it didn't.  You can find the log here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1199948/

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing a separate /boot partition at the start of your disk. See the end of your log file:

```
The boot files of [Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. 
You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). 
This can be performed via tools such as gParted. 
Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)
```

Tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition

Comment: Thanks.  I think I've got this thing partitioned correctly now, with a /boot partition of 200M, a / partition of 100G, a 150G partition for swap and a the rest mounted at /home.  Now I'm reinstalling.  Hope it works...

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: @mike If your problem is resolved, don't forget to close this question.